# Capture mouse messages when a ToolStripDropDown is shown

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown, mousecapture

I am trying to create a "tooltip" which contains a custom control. I implemented it using `ToolStripDropDown` which does what I need - closes when the user clicks somewhere else, or activates another window etc.

However, I'd like to be able to get the `MouseMove` event in the parent control even when the `ToolStripDropDown` is shown. I tried to set the `Capture` property of the parent control at various stages (before showing the dropdown, in its `Opened` event handler etc.) but it is always immediately set back to false. Is there a way (not necessarily employing the `Capture` property) to get the `MouseMove` event in the parent control? And no, I don't want to consider ugly hacks like using a timer and periodically checking the mouse position.

Comment: Right, it closes when clicking outside of the dropdown.  Getting an event when you click outside of a window requires a bit of magic.  It requires capturing the mouse.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I don't need to get `MouseDown` events, only `MouseMove` events. Which window gets these events when a `ToolStripDropDown` is shown but the mouse is outside of it?

Comment: The dropdown window gets them.  Because it captured the mouse.

Comment: I mean which window gets them if I don't set the `Capture` property manually, ie. I simply show the dropdown (for example a context menu).

Comment: You don't have any choice in the matter, the dropdown *must* capture the mouse and will thus *always* get the mouse messages.  It has to or it can't work correctly.  Not sure why this confuses you, other than that it happens in code that you cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the mouse position all the time, then you should register `MouseDown` event for both the parent control and the `ToolStripDropDown` control, something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lblPosition.Text = e.Location.ToString();
}

private void toolStripDropDownButton2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lblPosition.Text = e.Location.X + toolStripDropDownButton2.Bounds.Location.X + ", " + toolStripDropDownButton2.Bounds.Location.Y + e.Location.Y;
}
```

For `ToolStripDropDown` you should calculate the relative location to its parent